# Am I able to use the advantages of sealed classes using generics?

Tags: generics, kotlin, types, casting

I want to create a generic "find" method, that finds a provided entity that implements a sealed class and returns it without having to recur to polymorphism.

I wanted to do something like this, but I have not found a way that satisfies everything I want and compiles.

```java
sealed class Spell(val id: Long)
class Fireball(id: Long, val name: String): Spell(id)
class Storm(id: Long, val size: String): Spell(id)

inline fun <reified T: Spell> find(id: Long): T =
    when (T) {
        Fireball -> Fireball(id, "fireball")
        Storm -> Storm(id, "3 acres")
    }

fun main() {
    find<Fireball>(3)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
inline fun <reified T : Spell> find(id: Long): T =
    when (T::class) {
        Fireball::class -> Fireball(id, "fireball")
        Storm::class -> Storm(id, "3 acres")
        else -> throw IllegalStateException()
    } as T
```

Comment: Sure, this works, but I would like to break compilation when I add an entry to my sealed class and not have to deal with the default case, as it will never happen if I am exhaustive on the sealed class subtypes.
Thank you for your time, anyway.